# How can we add manifest to Lightning Web Component/Aura Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am trying to build a progressive web app for the Community, I am not sure how I can add the `manifest` and Service worker dependencies in the LWC/Aura Components.

I have found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_cache_manifest.htm) article which is for Visualforce Page. I looking for something similar to the Lightning Web components. I went through many resources on the web but could not find the solution. Is this possible? How?